# Azure AKS cluster admin access

Tags: azure

My friend has created a Aks cluster with resource-group = abc and name =abc.

He added my credentials as cluster-admin.

```
AKS_CLUSTER=$(az aks show --resource-group abc --name abc --query id -o tsv)

az role assignment create \
    --assignee $ACCOUNT_ID \
    --scope $AKS_CLUSTER \
    --role "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role for <Blah>"
```

When I login and check I get no output.

```
az aks list
```

Do, I need to do something more. Any pointers ?

Comment: Are you guys using the same subscription? If not, tell your friend to create for you a ``service principal`...then `az login` using the service principal information and also the subscription id, then you should be able to see the cluster

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service principal

```
az aks create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myAKSCluster \
    --service-principal <appId> \
    --client-secret <password>
```

then you need to log in with the subscription and service principal

```
az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --password PASSWORD --tenant TENANT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a service principal is a quick way to access the cluster, but one must appreciate this is not always fitting with security policy and that the principal is a completely separate from your own personal Azure AD account.

If you want to use your own account then a tenant admin should follow the steps outlined in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration